# Complex number Data type in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmath

> If I write x=5+j in python3. It shows me type(x) is an int. why this
> not considered as a complex number?

Comment: why it should be considered a complex number?? what is j??

Answer (score 2):

You forgot write number before `j` if you write `5+1j` and check `type` you get what you want *(complex type)*, like below:

```
x = 5+1j
type(x)
#complex
```

**For define complex numbers you can use different approaches.**

You can use `np.complex` like below:

```
import numpy as np
x  = np.complex(5,1)
type(x)
# complex
print(x)
# (5+1j)
```

Also You can use `cmath`:

```
import cmath

x = complex(5,1)
type(x)
# complex

print(x)
# (5+1j)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *cmath* module which allows you to work with complex numbers.

A very simple example of usage:

```
import cmath

x = 5 + 1*1j

# alternatively
# x = complex(5,1)

print(type(x))
print(x)
```

Check out more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html

It's a standard package, so you don't have to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `type(x)` is `int` probably means that you already have a variable `j` in your code, and that variable is an `int`. Just like this:

```py
>>> j = 10
>>> x = 5 + j
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
```

Now, if you wish to create a complex number, you may either use the built-in [`complex` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex):

```py
>>> x = complex(5, 1)
>>> x
(5+1j)
>>> type(x)
<class 'complex'>
```

or write a [literal complex number](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex):

```py
>>> x = 5 + 1j
>>> x
(5+1j)
>>> type(x)
<class 'complex'>
```

The main difference between this and what you wrote is that `5 + j` means "5 plus a variable called `j`", whereas `5 + 1j` means "5 plus the complex number `1j`". Remember that `j` *is not* the imaginary unit, it is the name of a variable. If you wish to write a complex literal, you need to write something like `<number>j`. In particular, the imaginary unit can be written as `1j`.